# How to show a question in a form based on selected answer for previous dropdown-menu-question (enum list)

Tags: forms, google-appsheet

I'm making a form in AppSheet that will be filled out by the user of the app. I have a table with questions for the columns. Question 1 contains an EnumList of answers, so the user can select multiple answers. What I want to do is display question 2 only if any of the answers in question 1 were selected. So if none were, then don't show question 2 so the user will answer question 3 next.

Comment: What kind of form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On AppSheet

1. Go to **Data**
2. Open the corresponding table
3. Go to **Columns**
4. Click on the Edit button of the column to be hidden
5. On the Show field, add formula, i.e. `ISNOTBLANK([Fruit])` (in this example `Fruit` is the column name).

[image]

6. Click Done

Comment: Maybe you have a typo or using it incorrectly ---> [ISBLANK()](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107337?hl=en)